# Show Soft Keyboard on AlertDialog or on Fragment with EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have two instances where as a user I would expect the soft keyboard to pop up but it does not.

One is on my custom fork of Chance.MvvmCross.Plugings.UserInteraction when showing an AlertDialog.  Below is the code:

```cs
public void Input(string message, Action<bool, string> answer, string hint = null, string title = null, string okButton = "OK", string cancelButton = "Cancel", string initialText = null, ValidationEnum validation = ValidationEnum.None)
{
    Application.SynchronizationContext.Post(ignored =>
    {

        if (CurrentActivity == null)
            return;

        var view = CurrentActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.input_dialog, null);
        EditText input = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.input_edit_text);
        input.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagAutoCorrect
            | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagCapWords
            | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText
            | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagAutoComplete;
        input.Hint = hint;
        input.Text = initialText;
        input.RequestFocus();

        var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentActivity)
            .SetMessage(message)
            .SetTitle(title)
            .SetView(view)
            .SetPositiveButton(okButton, (sender, args) =>
                {                        
                    // nothing - setting a button listener below
                })
            .SetNegativeButton(cancelButton, delegate
            {
                answer?.Invoke(false, input.Text);
            }).SetCancelable(false)
            .Create();

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        dialog.Window.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        int dialogHeight = dialog.Window.DecorView.Height;
        WindowManagerLayoutParams wmlp = dialog.Window.Attributes;
        wmlp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
        wmlp.Y = (height / 2 - dialogHeight) / 2;   // placing the middle of the dialog at about the 25% mark from the top

        dialog.Show();

        Button positiveButton = dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive);
        positiveButton.SetOnClickListener(new ValidatingOnClickListener(dialog, input, answer, validation));

    }, null);
}
```

In the above example, I would have expected dialog.Show() to force the soft keyboard to po-up yet it does not.  Wondering why?

The second is on a Fragment containing an AppCompatEditBox.  FragmentView is inherited from the BaseClass:

```cs
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.main_content_frame, true)]
[Register("...AddItemFragment")]
public class AddItemFragment : BaseFragmentWithUpNavigation<AddItemViewModel>, ITextWatcher
{
    #region properties

    protected override int FragmentResourceId => Resource.Layout.fragment_add_item;
    ...

    #endregion

    #region Fragment lifecycle overrides

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var addItemEditText = FragmentView
            .FindViewById<AppCompatEditText>(Resource.Id.add_item_edittext);
        addItemEditText.AddTextChangedListener(this);       // to catch text change events
        addItemEditText.RequestFocus();

        ...

        return FragmentView;
    }
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

I know its a lot of code but to the best of my knowledge, should't RequestFocus force the show of a soft keyboard?

Comment: AlertDialog: you need force soft keyboard pop up manually. And there is time difference you need notice.

Comment: Fragment: Do you mean you want show the soft keyboard when your fragment appear not after you click the `EditText`, or it can't appear after you click the `EditText`?

Comment: In both cases I want to have it appear after a) AlertDialog shows and b) Fragment appears.

Comment: I think you don't understand my meaning. Yes I know you want the soft keyboard to appear in both case.

Comment: For the Alert Button - how do I force soft keyboard to show/pop-up.  For the Fragment, yes, I want the keyboard to show after the fragment appears and not after I click the EditText.

Comment: Have you solved your question? Or does my solution work for you? Please leave me a message if you have seen this, thanks!!!!

Comment: @Joe, I have seen this.  Will try it out in the next couple of days.  Why is the timer delay required?  What prompted you to know/have this solution?

Comment: When you use `imm.ShowSoftInput(input, ShowFlags.Implicit);` to show the softkeyboard, the `input`--`EditText` is on the dialog, if the dialog isn't show on the screen, the `input` maybe is null, so use timer to show it. Also there is another solution [you can try](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Comment: Hi, it still not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> In the above example, I would have expected dialog.Show() to force the soft keyboard to po-up yet it does not. Wondering why?

You need add below code to force the soft keyboard to appear:

1) Add `dialog.SetOnShowListener(this);` above `dialog.Show();`, like this:

```
dialog.SetOnShowListener(this);
dialog.Show();
```

2) Implement `IDialogInterfaceOnShowListener` interface:

```
public void OnShow(IDialogInterface dialog)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Interval = 300;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
    imm.ShowSoftInput(input, ShowFlags.Implicit);
}
```

There is a time delay you need to deal with, so, use `System.Timers.Timer` class to achieve it.

---

In your Fragment, you just need add a `Timer` to do the same thing in your `AlterDialog` to force the soft keyboard appear.

Comment: I have a similar issue compare to the main post. I have a ThemedDialog that contains an EditText but when I click on the EditText the keyboard doesn't show up. Is there any solution for that?